# Restoring database without worring about partitions

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup, restore

On our our production database there is a partitioned table called `FullLog`. This is updated via triggers so we know who changed the database and when. Which is a problem for me when I restore the production database on our development servers as it doesn't have an F drive. Is there a easier way I can tell it to move to the specified location without knowing how many `ndf` files are there.

```
RESTORE DATABASE MartinUAT
  FROM DISK = 'C:\DBBaks\MARTIN_PreChange_2015_06_09_0800.bak'
  WITH MOVE 'CMTS_dat' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT_.mdf',
  MOVE 'P1' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__1.ndf',
  MOVE 'P2' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__2.ndf',
  MOVE 'P3' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__3.ndf',
  MOVE 'P4' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__4.ndf',
  MOVE 'P5' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__5.ndf',
  MOVE 'P6' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__6.ndf',
  MOVE 'P7' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__7.ndf',
  MOVE 'P8' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__8.ndf',
  MOVE 'P9' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__9.ndf',
  MOVE 'P10' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__10.ndf',
  MOVE 'P11' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__11.ndf',
  MOVE 'P12' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__12.ndf',
  MOVE 'P13' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__13.ndf',
  MOVE 'P14' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__14.ndf',
  MOVE 'P15' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__15.ndf',
  MOVE 'P16' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__16.ndf',
  MOVE 'P17' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__17.ndf',
  MOVE 'P18' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__18.ndf',
  MOVE 'P19' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__19.ndf',
  MOVE 'P20' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__20.ndf',
  MOVE 'CMTS_log' TO 'e:\SQLRestore\MARTIN_UAT__21.ldf'
  ,REPLACE
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest automating generation of the restore script. There are a few versions of this out there but [Paul Brewer has a T-SQL and PowerShell version available](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/restore-gene-version-3-free-public-framework-technical-article/).

I have seen some setups as well that just include generating a restore script when the backup is accomplished.

Which, just a note that a new open source backup solution was released by Sean and Jen McCown called [Minion Backup](http://minionware.net/backup/). It includes the functionality of generating your restore scripts and migrating backups to development.